# Singularity of an $l\times l$ matrix whose entries are $2l$-th roots of unity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $l$ be a positive integer, $\zeta$ be a primitive $2l$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, and $\alpha,\beta$ be $\pm1$ sequences of length $l$, i.e. $\alpha_k=\pm1,\beta_k=\pm1$ for $k=0,\dots,l-1$. Define $M(\alpha,\beta)$ to be the $l\times l$ matrix whose entry in $i$th row and $j$th column is $\alpha_{i-1}^{j-1}\beta_{j-1}^{i-1}\zeta^{(i-1)(j-1)}$.

**Question:** Is $M(\alpha,\beta)$ nonsingular for all $\alpha,\beta$?

If $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is constant, then since 
$$
\alpha_i^j\beta_j^i\zeta^{ij}=\alpha_i^j(\beta_j\zeta^j)^i=\beta_j^i(\alpha_i\zeta^i)^j,
$$ 
$M(\alpha,\beta)$ is equivalent to a Vondermonde matrix and thus nonsingular.

Comment: My experiments suggest that this matrix can be singular---however, due to numerical concerns, am not yet conclusively claiming singularity.

Comment: @suv....rit :Thanks! In your experiments, what is the smallest value of $l$ such that the matrix seems to be singular?

Comment: for me think broke at $l=40$, but should also break earlier---but I still suspect that this might be due to numerical roundoff (i.e., numerical rank was $l-1$)

Comment: @suv...rit: Which kind of reformulation did you use? For $l=40$, there are $2^{80}$ possibilities for the vectors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ...

Comment: This question has the flavor of a theorem of Chebotarev on the non-singularity of the minors of the matrix with entry $\zeta^{ij}$ in position $(i,j)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity for a prime $p$.

Comment: @PeterMueller: Yes. It seems that the fewer prime factors $l$ has, the easier the situation would be. So I think one may start the question when $l=p$ is prime (the $2p$th cyclotomic polynomial is also clear).

Comment: @Peter: I used $\alpha$ a random $\pm 1$ vector, and $\beta=[-1,1,-1,\ldots,]$. But I think I'm just running into round-off---

Comment: Checking *all* possibilities for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the answer is affirmative for all $\ell\le12$.

Comment: one minor point worth noting is that if $[\alpha_i^{j-1}\beta_j^{i-1}]$ is rank-1, (I'm running indices from $1,2,\ldots$), then $M=\text{diag}(\alpha)Z\text{diag}(\beta)$, which is clearly nonsingular. This begs the question: what is the largest rank that the matrix formed from the $\alpha$s and $\beta$s can have?